# iphone uitableview set description by code

Tags: iphone, uitableview, title, grouped-table

I have my uitableview created with grouped style..

I wish from my code set the description for the sections of my table..

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to elaborate on your question with more specifics, but I suggest you start by looking at the following table delegate method:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return <sectionName for section>;
}
```

Replace  with code to access the proper name for the section.